# xslt - How to check next node value and if same id, group child nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSLT and I'm wondering how to reduce the speed of one of our current XSLT's.. It's currently getting a lists of sports, and a list of groups, loops trough the groups and then trough the list of sports to see if they match.

If you have 200 groups and 50 sports, that's a quick 10.000 iteration.. This has to be done faster.

I was thinking about writing a new query that would deliver the outcome like this:

```
<groups>
   <group>
        <id>12</id>
        <sport>Football</sport>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>12</id>
        <sport>Hockey</sport>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>12</id>
        <sport>Swimming</sport>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>13</id>
        <sport>Tennis</sport>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>13</id>
        <sport>Basketball</sport>
    </group>
</groups>
```

This way you just would have to loop trough the result set, which is way less iterations. Each iteration should check if the next iteration has the same ID. True, then pass the sport as a param to the next iteration, if it's the 2nd iteration, it should pass them both to the next. Untill it arrives at a point where the next iteration doesn't has the same ID, this is where it should group the sports into a single object.

The expected outcome is like this:

```
<groups>
    <group>
        <id>12</id>
        <sport>Football</sport>
        <sport>Swimming</sport>
        <sport>Hockey</sport>
    </group>
    <group>
        <id>13</id>
        <sport>Tennis</sport>
        <sport>Basketball</sport>
    </group>
</groups>
```

I've been trying but with no luck, this is what my current xslt looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

<xsl:template name="main" match="/">

    <groups>
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*/row">
        <xsl:variable name="current" select="position()" />
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="*/*/row[$current + 1]" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="field[@name='GID'] = $next/field[@name='GIID']">
                <xsl:variable name="sports" >
                    <sport><xsl:value-of select="field[@name='SPORT']" /></sport>
                </xsl:variable>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count($sports) &gt; 0">
                        <xsl:call-template name="groups">
                          <xsl:with-param name="receivingSports" select="$sports" />
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:call-template name="groups" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:for-each>
    </groups>
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="groups">
    <xsl:param name="receivingSports" />
    <group>
            <xsl:value-of select="$receivingSports"/>
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="field[@name='BIID']" />
            </id>

    </group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If you want us to help to improve a stylesheet then please show a sample of the input you want to process and the corresponding output you want to achieve. Does your current XSLT compile at all? The use of `$sports` the way you have shown it doesn't seem possible at all. In general, the verbal description "How to check next node value and if same id, group child nodes" to me in XSLT 2.0 usually "translates" into `<xsl:for-each-group select="..." group-adjacent="id">...</xsl:for-each-group>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your problem is `xsl:for-each-group`.  (I assume you are using XSLT 2.0; if you are in a 1.0-only environment, the usual advice is to use Muenchian grouping (see answer by @JLRishe) and to consider taking steps to get out of that environment.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to do grouping in XSLT 1.0, a good solution will often use Muenchian Grouping, as it does here:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="sports" match="group" use="id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="group[generate-id() =
                                           generate-id(key('sports', id)[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="group">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="key('sports', id)/sport" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not only is it much faster than using `count`, it's also much more succinct.

When this is run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<groups>
  <group>
    <id>12</id>
    <sport>Football</sport>
    <sport>Hockey</sport>
    <sport>Swimming</sport>
  </group>
  <group>
    <id>13</id>
    <sport>Tennis</sport>
    <sport>Basketball</sport>
  </group>
</groups>
```